# How to transfer a stored procedure file to a directory into XML

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to find out how to transfer my stored procedure (which prints off an XML file in a console everytime I debug it in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop) into a directory folder using c#. Here is an example code to clarify my statement if it helps enough:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

namespace Web_Collage_feed
{
   public class CreateDirectory
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);
     Jack.Data.Sql work = new Jack.Data.Sql(con);
     con.Open();

     SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
     com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     DataSet data = work.ExecuteProcedureQuery("dbo.FEED_WebCollage", com);
     string productXml = data.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
     Console.WriteLine(productXml);
    }
   }
}
```

All of that code above allows me to open the **productXML** in a console window that contains XML contents within it. What I am trying to do is open that XML in a file (having that file stored in a directory folder) using c# programming techniques.

I am open to all kind of helps and suggestions (that would be greatly appreciated), if there are any questions you would like to ask then please let me know and I will reply to them as soon as I can and possibly edit the contents of my original question. Thank you for reading this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be going about this the wrong way. The DataSet class has methods that allow you to read and write XML. For example to save the dataset:

```
        using(var writer = new StreamWriter("path", false))
        {
            data.WriteXml(writer);
        }
```

Conversely, to read XML into a dataset from a file.

```
        var dataSetFromFile = new DataSet();
        using(var reader = new StreamReader("path"))
        {
            dataSetFromFile.ReadXml(reader);
        }
```

If you're after just reading and writing XML for strings rather than a dataset then take a look at this page on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bcctyt8.aspx

**Reading XML with the XMLReader** and **Writing XML with the XMLWriter** are the two pages that might most help.